# Avoid classes only used internally from being produced in generated CSS

Tags: html, css, less

Say I have the following LESS:

```
@accent: #00aa22;

.mainStyle
{
    border-radius:0.5em;
    border: 1px solid @accent;
}

#someElement
{
    .mainStyle;
}
```

I only ever use `.mainStyle` in my LESS, and never actually use it in my HTML for any elements. It's just being used to avoid repetition inside my LESS file.

In the generated CSS however, `.mainStyle` is redundant, since it's only used within my LESS.

Is there a way to exclude that class from the generated CSS while using it within the LESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this 20 seconds after asking the question...

You can make the class a parameterless mixin by adding brackets to the end:

```
.mainStyle()
{ ... }
```

Now its contents only appear where it's used in your LESS and never as a class in its own right in the generated CSS.

Comment: Why don't you add a reference to where you found the answer, it would make this even more useful to others.

Comment: I found it by trying it.

Comment: The reference for this would be in the LESS documentation on lesscss.org under [**Parametric Mixins**](http://lesscss.org#-parametric-mixins), where it says: ***"You can also use parametric mixins which don’t take parameters. This is useful if you want to hide the ruleset from the CSS output, but want to include its properties in other rulesets"*** and it also shows an example of this.